# Maven plugin java.library.path

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, java.library.path, sql-maven-plugin

The maven-surefire-plugin supports using the `java.library.path` property by means of the `<argLine>` configuration option.

I need to pass the `java.library.path` property to sql-maven-plugin (which doesn't have an `<argLine>` configuration option) in order to use the jTDS driver with windows authentication (needs ntlmauth.dll).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The surefire plugin is a special case; it runs the tests in a separate JVM. Most maven plugins don't do this, they run in-process.

So you are out of luck with that plugin config.

One workaround you can try is to use the `exec:exec` goal of the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) instead, specifying `java` with `-Djava.library.path` on the executable line and roll your own SQL-executing java code.

Otherwise, you can add `-Djava.library.path` to your `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable, which will affect all plugins and all maven builds (which might be fine, depends on your setup), or add it every time to the `mvn` command line.

Comment: With Intellij, you can globally set the VM options in the main IDE preferences, in the section:  Build tools > Maven > Runner